# What The Difference between stdio.h and iostream?

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    // code
}
return 0 ;
```

```
#include<iostream>
int main ()
{
    // code
}
```

Which library is best to use?

What is the best and why? And when I code what is the difference in function between them?

Comment: stdio.h is for printf ... while iostream is for std::cout / std::cin ...The difference is using c functions versus c++. If you are writing c++ code use c++.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`stdio.h` is the header file in the C standard library. It is used for input/output

`iostream` is the input output class in C++

So if you're using C++ just use `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 17):

First off, `iostream` is part of the C++ standard library, and `stdio.h` is part of the C standard library. While `stdio.h` will work in C++ it does not provide everything that `iostream` includes as `iostream` is specifically for C++.

Here is [`stdio.h` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/).

Here is [`iostream` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/).

Answer (score 8):

`iostream` is the C++ header for the input / output classes and objects (`std::cout`, `std::cin`...).
`stdio.h` is the C header for `printf`, `scanf`, ... (in C++, `stdio.h` became `cstdio`)

In C++, you are not supposed to use it, use `iostream` instead.